# Will installing node.js + npm on macOS using Homebrew prevent EACCES permission errors?

Tags: node.js, macos, npm, homebrew

Installing node.js and npm on macOS can cause EACCES permission errors when trying to install packages globally. A workaround is to reinstall npm with a node version manager (according to: https://docs.npmjs.com/resolving-eacces-permissions-errors-when-installing-packages-globally). I've seen a lot of tutorials that suggest installing npm using Homebrew, however. Would installing npm using Homebrew prevent EACCES permission errors?

Comment: Just do `$ sudo npm install -g [module-name]` if you have superuser privileges.

Comment: Yes home brew does it without admin rights. The only problem is to fully delete the original node before you install new